# PayPal payment in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, paypal

I would like to take payments via PayPal in my WPF application to shopping. I would like to generate a link for the user, but do not know how the application could be notified that the payment is accepted. Is the only solution will be to the server, which checks whether the payment has been accepted and the application will poll the server from time to time?

Comment: Too broad. It will all depend on what communication technology you are using

Comment: I generated link to payment and user pay for products in WebBrowser.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PayPal REST API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) and add a reference to PayPal

Nuget:

```
Install-Package Paypal
```

Comment: I have not found any helpful, I am new in PayPal payments. It is possible to user of my apps can be redirected to webbrowser and after succesfully payment my app be informed about it?

Comment: @user5492949 If you want you app to be notified of a PayPal payment you need to have your app communicate with PayPal. There are functions in the API to get transactions and transaction history. It's quite well documented in the link above. Your question is way to broad to give a simple answer, you need to read up on the API documentation and try to get it to work.

Comment: hmm, the dossier shows that in order to check the status of the transaction, my program needs to know my login and secret ID. I wan't not  to make a program that contains them to other users.

Comment: @user5492949 it's not your actual login ID and password, it a client ID and secret to authorize your app in PayPal. Take a look at [this page](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/dotnet?env=sandbox) where you can get a key for the sandbox environment.

Comment: @user5492949 Sorry, the link is wrong, [try this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps) instead.